# i want to update same table's value through trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
columns   data_type         nullable      default
ID        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No    
PASSWORD  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   No    
NAME      VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   No    
BIRTH     CHAR(11 BYTE)       No    
PHONE     VARCHAR2(11 BYTE)   No    
CBD_1     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes   
CBD_2     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes   
CBD_3     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes   
CBD_4     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes   
CBD_5     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes   
CDATE     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes      to_char(sysdate, 'dd-Mon-YYYY') 
UDATE     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes      to_char(sysdate, 'dd-Mon-YYYY')
```

My question is: I want to insert update time when I update existed record in this table through a trigger

and here is my code

```
create or replace trigger udate
  before update or delete on member for each row
declare
  u_id varchar2(30);
begin
  u_id := :old.id;
  update member set udate = to_char(sysdate, 'dd-Mon-YYYY') where id = u_id;
end;
```

error message

```
One error saving changes to table "JSP"."MEMBER":
Row 6: ORA-04091: table JSP.MEMBER is mutating, trigger/function may not see 
it
ORA-06512: at "JSP.UDATE", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'JSP.UDATE'
```

I already tried `:new.id` but it didn't work

Comment: Storing dates as `varchar` is a **horrible** idea. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `update`, simply assign the value:

```
create or replace trigger udate
  before update on member for each row
begin
  :new.udate := to_char(sysdate, 'dd-Mon-YYYY');
end;
```

Doing that "before delete" doesn't make sense, as the row will be deleted anyway.

---

You should **never** store DATE values in a `varchar` column. That is a horrible idea. Don't do that.

Comment: Thank you! it worked so well!! but i have some doubt about DATE values. i read some page that told saving date values in varchar is way better than in date for performance isn't  it true?

Comment: That site is completely and utterly wrong. A DATE takes less space than a varchar and is more efficient in comparison, but more importantly it validates the values. It will never let you store `My Date` in it, or `48-14-999`